# Android Emulator multiple error messages

Tags: android, sdk

I'm using Android Emulator on debian (in Android Studio), and when I start a new ADV I get multiple error messages, each after the other, and everyone multiple times:
"Unfortunately, Download Manager has stoppped."
"Unfortunately, Google Apps has stoppped."
"Unfortunately, Google Play services has stoppped."
"Unfortunately, the process android.process.media has stoppped."

I've assigned 1Gb space both to the SD Card and to the Internal Storage, and installed all the extras I could find in Android SDK Manager.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details by viewing the logs with logcat.

```
adb shell logcat
```

Messages "Unfortunately,  has stoppped" are shown when unhandled exception happened. In logcat you should be able to see them. It might help.

From my experience most likely your emulator has hardware/ABI issue. For example you might use ARM to x86 commands translator to be able to run Google Service on your emulator. It might cause problems like you describe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion BayK! logcat showed some permission errors, and running the avd with sudo fixed everything, now there's no error message.